# Comma separated Oracle string query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am expecting comma added output when passed two or more static strings.

```
SELECT ts.NAME
FROM ...
JOIN ...

WHERE ins.FEED_NAME = 'Trend' 
....

AND ts.NAME = 'beautiful' || 'chennai'
....
AND ins.USER_ID is NULL
ORDER BY ins.CREATED_AT DESC;
```

How can I get the output as **beautiful, chennai**

Comment: I reopened the post as the two values passed are static and not two different rows.

Comment: @OP Please post  a test case, i.e. create and insert statements. We don't have your tables, we don't have your data.

Comment: read up on the LISTAGG function.

Comment: `AND ts.NAME = 'beautiful' || 'chennai'` Are they two different rows you trying to refer to? Or, is it a single-value in the column `ts.name`? You probably mean, `ts.name IN ('beatiful', 'chennai')` in that case they are two different rows int he table, and you need `LISTAGG`. If the later is the case, then I will close it as duplicate as @a_horse_with_no_name mentioned.

Comment: Hello Lalit Kumar, I have the rows and I am trying to extract only those two colums data. Your comment solved my problem. I should be using ts.NAME IN.

Comment: @ItsZaif Ok, then just use `LISTAGG` as shown in the topic marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is selecting records from a table where the value of the column NAME is equal to 'beautiful' || 'chennai'.

|| means string concatenation in Oracle. So effectually you are selecting `NAME='beautifulchennai'`.

Maybe you want to select either the value 'beautiful' or the value 'chennai'?

Then you should select `NAME in ('beautiful','chennai')`